# Clear main image in gallery on mouseout of thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, image, gallery

I'm using script found here:

[Automatically load an image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009167/automatically-load-an-image-using-javascript)

I'm using them to build image gallery where the main image loads thumbnail image on `mouseenter`, but my main image begins blank not with the first thumbnail as in the answer. I need to know how to clear the main image back to blank on `mouseout` of each thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

Try JQuery [.mouseout()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) like this:

```
$('.thumbnails img').mouseout(function () {
    this.src = '';
});
```

Click http://jsfiddle.net/cnx65ev0/ to see it running. Hover over the images and when you leave them, they become blank. I hope this is what you wanted.